# Facebook Like button: is it possible to change the URL of a page you share?

Tags: html, facebook

Can I change the URL of a page shared through the facebook like button? Is there any meta tags for this?

Comment: You mean to change a link in already posted message? Or to change a link before posting it?

Comment: change the link before posting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are [generating code](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) for your like button it allows you to provide a url to like. If you want more customization options there is a whole set of [OpenGraph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) meta tags that let you set url, image, description for your liked page and more.